# what happens if there are 2 instances of a static variable

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Suppose I have a static library that I use in both my c++ application and a shared library this application uses. All the projects are compiled and work on some Linux machine.

The static library code is as follows:

```cpp
SomeRandomGenerator my_generator;

int32_t GetMyID()
{
    return my_generator.getNumber();
}
```

The real types/classes I am talking about are not important here I guess, the idea is that I have some random number generator( a class) as an global variable that is initialized once, at the beginning of the program.

That works as expected until I load a shared library that uses this static library too.

The project structure looks like this:

```
MyApplication
    MyStaticLibrary

MySharedLibrary
    MyStaticLibrary
```

The pseudocode looks like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::cout << "application started" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "my ID:" << GetMyID() << std::endl;
    do_task();
    std::cout << "my ID:" << GetMyID() << std::endl;
    load_dll();
    std::cout << "my ID:" << GetMyID() << std::endl;
}

void load_dll()
{
    std::cout << "dll loading" << std::endl;
    auto lib = dlopen("my_shared_lib.so");
}
```

and the output maybe as follows:

```
application started
my ID: 123456
my ID: 123456
dll loading
my ID: 789012
```

So I can quite understand and explain what is happening. I may well find a solution, such as, for example using shared library instead of the static one. But I really can't figure out what is going on with my global variable. There are 2 instances of that? The second one overrides the first one?

Comment: I suppose there is another shared library involved to which both of these "talk" to.

Comment: @tkausl did you mean the _static_ library? since a shared librray will contain only one instance on the global variable. the issue will exist only in case on the static lib only.

Comment: The static library, or rather the two instances of that class, talking to another shared library. I.e. one initializing something to X and the other initializing it _again_ to Y. Something like this.

Comment: Sure, this is what is really happening. The "pre-main" routine initializes the global variable and then the same does `dlopen()` while opening the shared library.

Comment: thanks @vvv444, actually yes, mainly this note: _Global and weak symbols are also preemptable, that is, they may by preempted by definitions of the same name in another component._

Comment: Two things, One don't use static global variables (use dependency injection, e.g. create an instance in main and pass it by reference to the code that needs to use it). Two : always put symbols in namespaces unique to each library

Comment: thanks @PepijnKramer of course I don't use the above code, my question is more theoretical than practical.